# Manifold $C^2$ and smooth manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I was looking for an answer to the following question. Is a $C^2$ real manifold a smooth manifold? I would think about no, for example the tangent space seem different so I would like to know more about the difference or similitudes

Comment: depends on what the author calls smooth...
usually smooth means $C^\infty$

Comment: Yes, smooth is $C^\infty$

Comment: Every maximal C^2 atlas contains a smooth atlas as set. So answer is yes